# How to exec the Windows Foto Viewer in order to show a png image using TCL

Tags: windows, image, tcl

In my TCL code running on windows I use

```
exec Notepad $somefilename
```

in order to show the content of a text file using the windows standard text editor.

How can I launch the standard windows image viewing application in order to show a png image?
I can not find the correct name of the standard viewing application.

Comment: Notice that Notepad need not be the system's default text editor. You can assign text files (such as `.txt` files) to any application you like. But I do agree that Notepad is the "default default" text editor in Windows. So, the question is: Do you want the default image viewer (for what image format?) or the "default default" image viewer (for what format?)?

Comment: I would like to use the "default default" viewer making it less dependend on a certain viewer. File format is *.png

Comment: You could use `pbrush` to launch Microsoft Paint. (That has been safe for decades, but might change very soon, since Microsoft might remove Paint from the standard Windows installation.)

Comment: Perhaps the best approach is to simply ask Windows to open the image in the associated application. Users often like it when software respect their settings. (For instance, I don't like it when applications open URLs in Internet Explorer when my default browser is Firefox. Similarly, I don't like it when text files open in Notepad and not my own text editor which is the default app associated with `.txt` files.)

Comment: Then the question turns into: How do I get the name of the standard image viewing application?